# What are sat Sandarbhas? What is the content of each sandarbha?

Tags: scripture

What are sad Sandarbhas? What is the content of each Sandarbha? What is the autocommentary on Sat Sandarbhas about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [Ravi M. Gupta's "The Chaitanya Vaishnava Vedanta of Jiva Goswami"](https://a91d4da009214563389d-2291296bddf53d3482c090e6456303db.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/TheChaitanyaVaishnavaVedanta1464788607923.pdf):

### Overview of the Sat-Sandarbhas

> The first four Sandarbhas deal primarily with sambandha-jnAna, that is, knowledge of God, the living entities, the world, and the relationships between
>   them. The Bhakti-sandarbha covers abhidheya, or the means of reviving the
>   personal relationship between the living entity and Bhagavan, while the final book, Priti-sandarbha, describes prayojana, the ultimate perfected state of
>   pure love for Krishna.
>
> The first three Sandarbhas address questions of ontology in a relatively non-sectarian way, using criteria of knowledge and proof-texts that would
>   be acceptable to an audience much broader than the followers of Caitanya. Only when major issues regarding the status of the world, the personal
>   nature of divinity, and the individuality of the jiva have been settled does
>   Jiva Gosvami go on (in the Krishna Sandarbha) to identify that divinity with
>   Krishna and describe his unique characteristics, relying on scriptural sources
>   that are more internal to the tradition. This is interesting, for it means that Jiva exhaustively describes Bhagavan without seriously describing Krishna; that he explains the concept of lila without addressing rasa; and that he
>   establishes the status of the internal energy (antaranga Shakti) without mentioning Sri Radha. Of course, in the process of elaborating the qualities and
>   characteristics of Bhagavan, Jiva broadly identifies him with Vishnu/Krishna, but this is an assumption that many Vedantic writers will make, if only for the sake of demonstrating the applicability of general principles. Vishnu/Krishna is present throughout the first three Sandarbhas, but not in the way Caitanya Vaishnavas know him. Krishna, the son of Nanda Maharaja, the Lord of the cows, and the beloved of Sri Radha emerges only in the later
>   treatises.
>
> This kind of less-sectarian approach is a clear indicator of Jiva’s Vedantic
>   intentions in the first three Sandarbhas. Engagement in Vedantic discourse
>   requires awareness of a universe of discourse much broader than one’s own
>   community. Eric Lott notes, for example, that there is a “striking difference
>   in style” between Ramanuja’s Vedantic writings and his devotional ones.
>   “There is a remarkable avoidance of strictly sectarian material when he
>   writes as a Vedantin, even though his Vedantic formulation remains based scrupulously on the theology of his Vaishnava tradition.” While it is true that
>   “it is in the very nature of a theistic interpretation of Vedanta to remain
>   closely associated with a particular religious community,” still, a theist such
>   as Ramanuja or Jiva would not “intend his Vedantic writings solely for his
>   own sect”. In the case of Caitanya Vaishnavism, such sectarianism
>   would go against one of the main motivations for Vedantic discourse identified in Chapter 1 of this book, namely, to provide a generally acceptable,
>   philosophical foundation for the practice of bhakti.

### Tattva-sandarbha

> The Tattva-sandarbha is the most widely read and frequently used of the six
>   Sandarbhas. It is the only one to have been commented upon by Baladeva
>   Vidyabhusana, the eighteenth-century author of the Govinda-bhashya, and it has received more scholarly attention in English than any other Sandarbha.
>   This could simply be attributed to the fact that the Tattva is the first, shortest, and simplest of the six Sandarbhas, consisting of only 63 sections (anucchedas). It could also be attributed, however, to the fundamental nature
>   of its subject matter. The Tattva lays down the foundation upon which Jiva
>   Gosvami builds his philosophical and theological edifice, as well as the
>   methodology by which he does it.
>
> That Tattva-sandarbha has traditionally been divided into two parts: the
>   prameya-khanda, which deals with the standards of knowledge and metho-
>   dology to be used in the text, and the prameya-khanda, which delineates
>   the theses to be demonstrated by these methods. Jiva’s main concern in the
>   first part is to demonstrate the preeminence of the Bhagavata Purana over
>   all other forms of scripture, and its exclusive status as the best means of
>   certain knowledge (pramAna). He does this by first discussing the tradition-
>   ally accepted pramAnas, such as sense perception (pratyaksha), inference
>   (anumAna), and analogy (upamAna), and rejecting them because of their
>   unreliability in ascertaining a transcendental subject matter. The only pramAna
>   that is dependable and faultless in this regard is sabda—the testimony of perfected souls given through scriptural revelation.
>
> The crucial question then is: what qualifies as sabda?, and Jiva dedicates
>   the majority of the first part to answering this question. The unchallenged
>   repository of scriptural revelation is, of course, the Veda, but what the
>   category of Veda includes is initially not clear. The four samhitas— Rig, Yajur, SAma, and Atharva—as well as the Upanishads are universally accepted,
>   but Jiva argues further for the inclusion of the Puranas, Mahabharata, and
>   Ramayana as the “fifth Veda.” He cites numerous passages in support, mainly from the Puranas themselves, but also from the Upanishads. Not only are
>   the Puranas included in the Veda, Jiva reasons, but they are in fact better than the rest of Vedic literature because they are available to all classes of
>   people. They are more easily understood by the people of this degraded age (kali-yuga), and they present the intended meaning of the Upanishads and four Vedas. Of all the Puranas, however, the Bhagavata is the topmost, being spotless (amala). Jiva rests this claim on supporting quotations from various Puranas as well as the Bhagavata itself.
>
> The second part of the Tattva-sandarbha can be seen as a detailed elaboration of verses four to eleven of the first book, seventh chapter of the Bhagavata PurAna. These verses describe the trance of Vyasa, the author of the Bhagavata. While meditating, Vyasa saw the Supreme Person and his
>   external energy, which deludes the living entities and causes their misery. He
>   also saw that the masses were ignorant of the fact that devotion to the Lord could bring an end to their suffering. He therefore composed the Bhagavata Purana for their upliftment, and afterwards taught it to his son Sukadeva.
>   At this point, the question is raised, “Why did Sukadeva study this vast composition, given that he was already leading a life of perfection?” Suta
>   Gosvami answers with the famous verse: “Although these sages rejoice in the self alone and although they are free of all bonds, they still perform
>   unmotivated bhakti for Urukrama (Vishnu). Such are qualities of Hari!”
>
> Jiva takes this verse (along with those preceding it) as relaying the basic
>   import of the Bhagavata Purana. Drawing various philosophical conclusions from them, he uses the next dozen or so sections to argue against Sankara’s
>   nondualism. He attempts to show that the living entity is not the supreme
>   Brahman, but distinct from him; that the doctrines of pratibimba and
>   pariccheda are fatally flawed; that Vyasa’s experience does not support a nondualist view; that apparently nondualist statements in the scripture need
>   to be interpreted in light of Vyasa’s experience; and that love of God is
>   superior even to the bliss of Brahman.
>
> Jiva goes on to analyze Vyasa’s trance in terms of the categories of
>   sambandha, abhidheya, and prayojana. He states that the purpose of the
>   Sandarbhas is to ascertain these three things, and he will do so in accordance with the understanding of Vyasa.

### Bhagavata Sandarbha

> As its name implies, the Bhagavata Sandarbha lays out the complete Caitanya Vaishnava doctrine of Bhagavan—the personal, supremely worshipable, and
>   blissfully active repository of all powers, Sri Krishna. But, unlike the Krishna Sandarbha, which deals specifically with the theology surrounding the person of Krishna, the Bhagavata is interested more in the philosophical justification
>   for divine personhood. Jiva Gosvami deals with the problems posed by a
>   God who is eternally active and yet eternally unchangeable (avikAra), who is full of unlimited attributes and yet undifferentiated (nirvisesa), and who is the creator of the phenomenal world and yet unsullied by its qualities
>   (nirguna).
>
> It is in this Sandarbha that Jiva Gosvami introduces the Caitanya Vaishnava doctrine of a three-fold Absolute. Although the Absolute Truth is nondual and indivisible, it has three aspects: Brahman (the undifferentiated, impersonal Reality), Paramatma (the localized form of the Lord present in every
>   part of the creation), and Bhagavan (the supreme, blissful Person who is the object of devotion). The Paramatma and Bhagavan aspects are discussed in the Sandarbhas named after them. There is no need for a separate Sandarbha
>   to explain Brahman because, Jcva reasons, anyone who understands Bhagavan automatically knows Brahman. Besides, undifferentiated Brahman has already been thoroughly described by the nondualist school of Advaita Vedanta.
>
> Fundamental to the Caitanyite understanding of Bhagavan is the idea of God as the possessor of all energies (sakti). Jiva dedicates the majority of
>   the Bhagavata-Sandarbha to delineating and justifying the concept of sakti.
>   He classifies the Lord’s energies into three types—the mAyA-sakti (the material energy which constitutes and creates this phenomenal world), jiva-sakti (the living entities), and svarupa-sakti (the Lord’s personal energy which consists of his own nature). He further divides the svarupa-Uakti into three
>   kinds: sandhini (the Lord’s power of existence), samvit (the power of know-
>   ledge), and hlAdini (the power of bliss). These correspond approximately to
>   the Vedantic categories of sat, cit, and Ananda associated with Brahman.
>   Another concept introduced in the Bhagavata Sandarbha is lila, divine play. When faced with the question, “For what reason does Bhagavan display his saktis?,” Jiva answers that it is simply for the purpose of play (lila). Play is
>   part of the essential nature of Bhagavan, arising out of his natural blissfulness.
>
> Another concept introduced in the Bhagavata-Sandabrha is lila, divine play. When faced with the question, “For what reason does Bhagavan display his saktis?,” Jiva answers that it is simply for the purpose of play (lila). Play is part of the essential nature of Bhagavan, arising out of his natural blissfulness.

### Paramatma Sandarbha

> After discussing the concept of Bhagavan, Jiva Gosvami turns his attention to the second aspect of the three-fold Absolute, namely, Paramatma. Whereas Bhagavan displays all the energies and opulences of the Absolute, Paramatma manifests them only partially. Specifically, Paramatma is the form of the Lord meant to deal with the workings of the material world and the living
>   entities within it.
>
> Because the Paramatma works so closely with the material energy and the living entities, the majority of this Sandarbha is dedicated to elucidating the
>   nature of these two and their relation to the Lord. Jiva Gosvami asserts that while the Paramatma is only one, the living entities (jivas) are many. Each jiva is eternally an individual, different from every other jiva. Nevertheless, the jivas all possess the same divine nature. They are eternal, conscious, immutable, pure, and always dependent on the Paramatma.
>
> The material energy (maya) can be the cause of both bondage and eman-
>   cipation for the jivas. It has two main functions—to deal with the entangled living entities and to provide for the creation, maintenance, and dissolution
>   of the phenomenal world. In its role with the living entities, it can either liberate them through the power of knowledge (vidya) or delude them by the power of ignorance (avidya). Although maya is not part of Bhagavan’s essential nature (svarupa), and although he is beyond its binding influence, it
>   nevertheless rests within Bhagavan and arises from him.
>
> Questions concerning the nature of jiva and maya are a major locus of
>   disagreement between Vedantic schools of thought. As such, the Paramatma Sandarbha serves to a large extent as the Caitanya Vaishnava statement against
>   conflicting philosophies, especially the traditional archrival, Advaita Vedanta. Jiva Gosvami uses the concepts already introduced in the Bhagavata-Sandarbha
>   to establish the Caitanyite viewpoint on problems of general concern. The arguments against the doctrines of pariccheda and pratibimba outlined in the
>   Tattva-sandarbha are developed in detail here. The nondualist doctrine of vivarta (the world as apparent transformation) is rejected in favor of sakti-parinama-vada (the world as a transformation of the Lord’s energy). The
>   Sankhya analysis of the field (kshetra) and the knower of the field (kshetrajña)
>   is modified to accommodate a more theistic viewpoint. The theory of one-ness between living entity and Brahman is replaced by a doctrine of incon-ceivable difference and non-difference (acintya-bhedAbheda). And the worship of gods like Brahma and Shiva is presented as inferior to, and subsumed within, the worship of Vishnu or Krishna.

### Krishna Sandarbha

> The primary concern of this work is to establish Krishna as Bhagavan. A single phrase is chosen from the previously agreed upon scriptural authority, namely the Bhagavata Purana, and established as the maha-vakya—the defining statement of the entire Purana. This phrase comes from a verse found in chapter 3 of book one. It appears immediately after the Bhagavata’s description of twenty-two different divine descents (avatAras): “ete camsa kalah pumsah krisnas tu bhagavan svayam,” “These avataras are portions and subportions of the Supreme Person, but Krishna is BhagavAn himself.” (1.3.28). Jiva asserts that because this statement is the mahavakya, all contradictory statements found in the BhAgavata and other scriptures must be reconciled to this one. He then goes on to demonstrate this hermeneutical method on several apparently contradictory passages. He also marshals a host of passages from various texts confirming the maha-vakya.
>
> Just as Sri Krishna is the highest Deity, so everything and everyone related
>   to him are also the best of their kind. Srimati Radha, Krishna’s consort and greatest devotee, is the embodiment of his personal energy—specifically his
>   power of bliss (hladini-sakti). She is superior even to Lakshmi and the queens of Dvaraka, who are lesser manifestations of this same Uakti. Krishna’s residence, Goloka, is the highest abode in the celestial sky, greater than the abodes of Vishnu. His youthful, two-handed form is the original, most essential, and sweetest form of the Godhead, more attractive than those forms with many hands or non-human shapes.
>
> The Krishna-sandarbha borrows much of its content from Rupa Gosvami’s
>   Laghu-bhagavatAmrta. Both works deal extensively with the theory of divine descent and provide a detailed classification of their types and relative importance. They accept and delineate the Pancaratra system of catur-vyuhas-forms of Vishnu appearing in sets of four to facilitate creation. Both introduce the categories of manifest (prakata) and unmanifest (aprakata) in relation to Krishna’s pastimes and affirm that these pastimes are being played out eternally in one of these states. Similarities are also obvious in the discussion of the Lord’s abode (dhama) and associates (parikara). There are a number of quotations from the Purawas and Tantras which are used by both Rupa and Jiva.

### Bhakti Sandarbha and Priti Sandarbha

> While it is evident that Jiva drew heavily from the works of Rupa and
>   Sanatana in his last three Sandarbhas, this was by no means a simple repetition of their teachings. The special way in which he formulates and presents
>   their doctrines reveals Jcva’s priorities in composing the Sandarbhas.
>
> In the Bhakti and PrCti Sandarbhas, Jiva Gosvami borrows from two works by Rupa Gosvami on the aesthetics of devotion—the Bhakti-rasAmrita-sindhu and the Ujjvala-nilamani. The former is divided into four parts, each
>   named after a directional ocean. From a preliminary comparison of the last two Sandarbhas with Bhakti-rasAmrita-sindhu, it appears that the Bhakti-Sandarbha corresponds roughly to the first part (eastern ocean) of Rupa’s work. The Priti-sandarbha then picks up on the subject matter of the remaining three oceans as well as the Ujjvala-nilamani.
>
> In the Bhakti-sandarbha, Jiva restricts his treatment of bhakti to the stage
>   of regulated devotional practice (sadhanAa). He discusses its two levels and
>   the specific practices associated with each. He introduces the nine types of
>   devotion and the primary rasas. Jiva also provides us with a general description of bhakti in terms of its essential characteristics (svarupa-laksana) and
>   accidental characteristics (tatastha-laksana).
>
> While the Bhakti-Sandarbha charts the path of devotion (abhidheya),
>   the Priti-Sandarbha reveals its ultimate destination and reward (prayojana), namely priti—unmotivated, unceasing love for Krishna. This love consists of
>   a variety of rasas—intensified emotional states of love expressed in various
>   relationships between the Lord and his devotees. In the Priti-sandarbha, Jiva Gosvamc enters more deeply into the intricacies of rasa theology. He makes a thorough analysis of the five primary rasas, as well as the seven
>   secondary ones. He discusses the successive stages in the appearance and growth of these sentiments in the devotee. He highlights the amorous sentiment (madhurya-rasa) as the perfection of love for Krishna. Through this discussion, Krishna himself emerges as the overflowing reservoir of all rasa
>   and its chief relisher as well.
>
> Although Jiva follows Rupa Gosvami faithfully in his account of bhakti
>   and rasa, there are important differences in approach and emphasis. The
>   relative space Jiva allocates to the exoteric and esoteric aspects of devotion
>   is especially significant. While Rupa devotes only one part (the eastern ocean)
>   of the Bhakti-rasamrita-sindhu to regulated practice, Jiva dedicates an entire Sandarbha to its exposition. He places sadhana at the heart of his largest
>   Sandarbha and thus firmly grounds bhakti in the exoteric, regulated practice
>   of the devotee.
>
> Even when Jiva deals with the higher levels of rasa, he prefaces and intersperses his discussion with philosophical considerations that may have
>   been of less concern to Rupa Gosvami. Towards the beginning of Priti-Sandarbha, for example, Jiva includes a lengthy discussion on mukti, liberation. He classifies their different types, assesses their relative worth, and identifies their primary characteristics. Only after thoroughly analyzing the
>   concept of liberation, and rejecting it as the final goal, does he proceed to
>   the main topic of the Sandarbha. Similarly, Jiva Gosvami begins Bhakti-Sandarbha by addressing questions that underlie the devotional quest itself.
>   What need is there to perform bhakti in the first place? Is bhakti simply the means to something higher, or is it an end in itself? Where does bhakti stand in relation to other recognized paths to liberation such as the cultivation of
>   knowledge (jnana), action (karma) or yoga? And is bhakti capable of standing on its own as a spiritual process, or must it be accompanied by these others? Jiva is also keen to anticipate and respond to possible objections in
>   the course of his argument. It is as if he expects his reader to be a person of mild skepticism who will test the coherence of the system by introducingevidence from conflicting sources or by questioning the validity of the author’s sources. One objection, for example, comes from the realm of orthodox poetics, which regards bhakti as merely bhava (emotion) rather than full-fledged
>   rasa. Jiva’s rebuttal is of great theoretical interest, for Caitanya Vaishnava aesthetics rests on the proposition that bhakti is rasa.

Comment: Any information about autocommentary i mean sarva samvadini?

Comment: @KrishnaVarna Check the url now

Comment: Thanks!! can you write about sarva samvadini?

Comment: @KrishnaVarna Here's some info about Sarva Samvadini: some info about sarva samvadini is here:  https://bkdemian.blogspot.com/2011/02/sarva-samvadini.html